# how to run fio verify reliably in linux

Tags: linux, disk, io, storage, utilities

I am using `fio` over disks exposed through iscsi. I am giving these params in `fio`

```
fio --name=randwrite --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=64 --rw=randrw --rwmixread=50  --bs=4k-2M --direct=1 -filename=data --numjobs=1 --runtime 36000 --verify=md5 --verify_async=4 --verify_backlog=100000 --verify_dump=1 --verify_fatal=1 --time_based --group_reporting
```

With the above parameters can `fio` send overlap concurrent writes of size more than page size.

If yes, then how does `fio` verify the checksum because atomicity of io is not guaranteed across page size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [fio's `serialize_overlap` option](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-serialize-overlap)? You're correct that if fio submits a verifying read to an area it has a write in flight for and the read then the race can lead to spurious failures. I think someone else noticed this and filed an issue for it over on https://github.com/axboe/fio/issues/792 ...